# Why it keeps iterating through the array elements multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to output all the values from the array with 'title element' There are 10 values - titles. PROBLEM:

1. The for loop output all 10 values but it does this 10 times again.

Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
Title 5
Title 6
Title 7
Title 8
Title 9
Title 10

(OUTPUT AGAIN 10 TIMES)

How can I solve this cannot get my head around it, the code:
This function add the data in the array  `p_marker.push(marker);`.

```
function placesToVisitMarker(results, status) {
    image = 'pin56.png';
    console.log(results);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[i].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: results[i].name,
            icon: image
        });

        distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [currentLocation],
            destinations: [results[i].geometry.location],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
        }, callback);
        p_marker.push(marker);
    }
}
```

This function is were I suppose to output the title and distance into the `#list div`

```
function callback(response, status) {
    if (status = "OK") {
        for (var i = 0; i < p_marker.length; i++) {
            $("#list").append(p_marker[i].title + "</br>");
        }
        //$("#list").append( +" "+ response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text + "</br>")        
    } else {
        $("#list").append("ERROR" + status);
    }
}
```

Comment: console.log(results); ? what does it print ? And what is thr in p_marker ?

Comment: in placesToVisitMarker, u r adding one element each tym to p_marker. Then, in callback, u r looping through the elements of p_marker again. Its like, for loop inside placesToVisitMarker is called 10 times, and for each tym, callback is adding title that many number of times as many element p_marker has. U seem to have problem thr.

Comment: (Not directly related to your question) Your code seems to have a `==` missing in `if (status = "OK") {`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I see what your saying, I did not realize that the call back is inside another for loop which makes sense iterating it again 10 times, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @collapsar Yep did not see that one but it was not producing any error, thanks.

Comment: I have added an answer @DubPro. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop inside callback method was causing problem, here is the solution that might help,

In placesToVisitMarker, u r adding one element each tym to p_marker. Then, in callback, u r looping through the elements of p_marker again. Its like, for loop inside placesToVisitMarker is called 10 times, and for each tym, callback is adding title that many number of times as many element p_marker has. U seem to have problem thr.

And the question about why it was getting printed 10 times :

**The reason was, your callback method's for loop was referring to p_marker, 
and by the time callback was called, p_marker had 10 elements in it. So, for each callback call, 10 title was getting appended to list.**

Solution :

**You should remove 'for' loop inside your callback method. And give 'callback' function access to the particular 'i' value so that proper title is appended to list.**

```
function placesToVisitMarker(results, status) {
    image = 'pin56.png';
    console.log(results);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[i].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: results[i].name,
            icon: image
        });
        p_marker.push(marker);

        // use closure here to make the function remember about the 'i'
        // else what would happen is by the time callback will be 
        // called, i value would be 10, so same element 
        // will get appended again and again.
        (function(i) {
              distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
                  origins: [currentLocation],
                  destinations: [results[i].geometry.location],
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
              }, 
             function(response, status) {
                  if (status == "OK") {
                       $("#list").append(p_marker[i].title + "</br>");   
                  } else {
                       $("#list").append("ERROR" + status);
                  }

             });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: How was the loop causing the problem? What have you changed to fix that? Why did you do it that way? A really good Stack Overflow answer would explain those things rather than just giving them the working code; the intention is to create useful resources for all future visitors with similar problems, not just to solve the question for the one person who asked it.

Comment: Sorry, was updating my answer for the same. Had posted reasons in comment, so missed. Thanks for reminding :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However, I really do not understand your answer, but I came up with a solution and got it figured out, might not be effecient, I just decided to create another array that will store the `response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text` - which are the distance then create another function to display the values within those two arrays. Therefore, I can then loop through the two array to output the tilte and distance: `function displayPlacesDistance()
{
 for(var i=0; i<p_marker.length; i++)
 {
  $("#list").append(p_marker[i].title + " " + placeDist[i] + "</br>"); 
 }
}`

Comment: @Nielarshi +1 want to up your answer but I need to have 15 reps, thanks very much!